# Django Placeholders

Tags: python, django

I want to insert placeholders for username, password and password2 inputs which are provided by this django module "django.contrib.auth.models.User"

```
from django import forms
#from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm      

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),required = True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),required = False)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','username', 'password1', 'password2',]
        widgets={

                'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}),
                'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}),
                'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}),
               }        

    def save(self,commit = True):   
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']


        if commit:
            user.save()


        return user
```

Comment: OK, so you seem to have some code. Now what happens? What's going wrong? What is your question?

Comment: i am trying to display placeholders for username, password1 and password2 from the User model but its not working

Comment: "It's not working" is not at all helpful. What do you see? How do you output your fields in the first place?

Comment: sorry sir, the fields under the RegistrationForm class are working but since i am using the inbuilt User field (username, password1, password2) i was trying to display their respective placeholders by the use of 
widgets={

                'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}),
                'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}),
                'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}),
               }

Comment: Why don't you define those three fields in the same way as the other three?

Comment: let me try again it projected an error when i tried it

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you sir i will post the working code for anyone who might face the same problem in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the working code

```
from django import forms
#from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm      

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),required = True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),required = False)
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}),required = True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}),required = True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}),required = True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','username', 'password1', 'password2',]


    def save(self,commit = True):   
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']


        if commit:
            user.save()


        return user
```